# Force IDA starter 6.5 to disassemble encrypted in autonomous mode

Tags: ida, idapython, automation

I'm using IDA Starter 6.5 on linux. (Debian Wheezy 32bit)
I would like to perform batch analysis on a bunch of iOS apps with an IDAPython script.
To do so, I use command as such, to call text interface:

```
$ ~/.ida-6.5/idal -A -SDump.py my_app
```

However, it just flashed out in a sec and quited before any analysis happened.
The only thing I saw on the last line of IDA is:

The file is encrypted. The disassembly of it will be likely useless.
Do you want to continue? ? -> N~o

Anyone know how to make it Yes so I can use command line?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to modify LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO as fellow and it works!

http://www.infointox.net/?p=114

Just be sure for multiple architectures, choose correct bytes to filp.

Comment: to get rid of multiple architectures, using lipo to extract correct version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `yes` command.

```
yes | ~/.ida-6.5/idal -A -SDump.py my_app
```

Comment: It says: "TVision error: Can not work with redirected stdin/stdout". It seems tvision library won't accept the trick.